# Postgresql- (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at end of input

Tags: sql, postgresql

below is the table schema and I am trying to keep the join of two tables in a cte as follows but I am getting this error which I am not able to figure out. I tried checking the syntax on official documents page but nothing worked. Can someone help please? Thanks.

Schema:

db_employee

```
id int
first_name    varchar
last_name     varchar
salary        int
department_id int
```

db_dept

```
id         int
department varchar
```

My code:

```
with de as (select e.*, d.department from db_employee
e
join
db_dept d
on e.department_id=d.id)
```

Error:
(psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at end of input
LINE 5: on e.department_id=d.id)

Comment: The issue may be that you are not selecting anything from `de` after your `with` statement.

Comment: Per @KurtKline you have only created the front half of the total query. For examples see [WITH](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html).

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much.